# saving and restoring rich rules in some file using firewalld in RHEL 7

Tags: firewall

Though this feature is available in iptables using save and restore, but my requirement is firewalld. I could use --permanent option to be able to retrieve it later but i want to import and export those rules from and to other machines.I viewed firewalld configuration files too but couldn't get the one where rules are stored. Does anybody know how to use this save and restore feature in FIREWALLD in redhat 7 ??

Comment: This does not appear to be a programming-related question.  You might be better off asking on ServerFault or SuperUser.

Answer (score 1):

Firewalld stores its configuration in `/etc/firewalld` and within that directory you can find various configuration files:

- `firewalld.conf` provides overall configuration.
- Files in the `zones` directory provide your custom firewall rules for each zone.
- Files in the `services` directory provide custom services you have defined.
- Files in the `icmptypes` directory provide custom icmptypes you have defined.

There is a matching directory structure in `/usr/lib/firewalld` which provides the *defaults* for zones, services and icmptypes, in case you want to start customizing from a template, or simply see what the files look like.

With the Firewalld package, the firewall configuration of the main services (ftp, httpd, etc) comes in the /usr/lib/firewalld/services directory. But it is still possible to add new ones in the /etc/firewalld/services directory. Also, if files exist at both locations for the same service, the file in the /etc/firewalld/services directory takes precedence.

Comment: I got that, in .xml file. But how to use the same zone file on different system by exporting it without replacing but appending the existing zone file in destination system? Like we had rule-save and rule-restore  in iptables. Is there any such command in firewalld?